# Karabiner - How do I make a button send keypresses (not key repeat) repeatedly while it is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I am trying to replicate Razer Synapse's "Repeat while the key is pressed" capability using Karabiner. I would like to press the "a" key on my keyboard, and as long as I hold it down, it will send the "b" key down and then "b" key up to the active window. "Key repeat" isn't what I need. I need it to send individual keypresses (key down, key up) for as long as I hold the key down. This was simple with Razer Synapse, but apparently, it is beyond my comprehension how to make this work with a Mac.

Comment: TIL. Never knew there was a difference until now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbNCU.png

Comment: Do you really want to hold the "a" key down and have it send "b" down and "b" up?